# Find value of n, in vectors

Tags: vectors

Relative to an origin O, the position vectors of the points A, B, C, and D are given by:

> $\vec{OA}=(1,3,-1) \vec{OB}=(3,-1,3) \vec{OC}=(4,2,m), \vec{OD}=(-1,0,n)$
>
> where  and  are constants. Find
>
> a) The unit vector in the direction of $\vec{AB}$
>
> b) The value of  for which angle  = $90^\circ$
>
> c) The values of  for which the length of $\vec{AD}$ is $7$ units

Here is what I got :

a)  $\frac{2}{6}i+\frac{4}{6}j\frac{-4}{6}k$

b) For this part, I'm not sure I got m=10? can anyone confirm, please?

c) I'm not sure how to do this

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbf{Hint:}$

b) For $2$ vectors that are perpenicular to each other use 
$\mathbf{a\cdot b}=0$

c) Find $AD$ in terms of $n$. Can you use the distance formula to form an equation in $n$?

Edit:
The distance formula for $3$ dimensions is :

$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

Comment: b) you mean $\mathbf{a\cdot c}=0 ?$
i found m=10, can u confirm ?

c)i don't know the distance formula, why should i use that for this?

Comment: For c), the distance formula is basically the Pythagorean theorem. For example, the distance from $(3,7)$ to $(1,2)$ is $\sqrt{(3-1)^2 - (7-2)^2}$, and the case in three dimensions is similar but with one more dimension to square, like the 3D Pythagorean theorem. You can use the distance formula to set up an equation which will let you find $n$.

Comment: I edited my answer so it includes the distance formula

Comment: also $m=10$ is correct